# Getting a 404 ERROR when trying to make api POST request for a Hubspot form next.js app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm currently working on building out a Hubspot email submission form through nextjs and typescript but keep getting a few error and not sure how to solve. The first one is an error with my 'response' constant saying it's declared but not used and not sure how to solve and the second error is a 404 axios error. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here's the api:

```
import axios from 'axios'
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'

const HUBSPOT_API_KEY = process.env.HUBSPOT_API_KEY
const HUBSPOT_PORTAL_ID = '22316985' // Replace this
const HUBSPOT_FORM_GUID = '5d0cab17-2376-44bc-bbe9-cb477bff0360' // Replace this

type Response = {
  success: boolean
  email?: string
}

export default async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse<Response>) => {
  const { email, pageUri } = req.body

  if (typeof email !== 'string') {
    return res.status(400).json({ success: false })
  }

  try {
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
    const response = await axios({
      method: 'POST',
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-useless-escape
      url: `https://api.hsforms.com/submissions/v3/integration/secure/submit/${HUBSPOT_PORTAL_ID}/${HUBSPOT_FORM_GUID}/?hapikey/=${HUBSPOT_API_KEY}`,
      data: {
        fields: [{ name: 'email', value: email }],
        context: { pageUri }
      },
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
    })
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json({ success: false })
  }

  res.status(200).json({ success: true, email })
}
```

Here's the index.tsx file:

```
 const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
  const [pageUri, setPageUri] = useState<string>()
  const [{ loading }, refetch] = useAxios(
    {
      url: '/pages/api/emailSignup',
      method: 'POST',
      data: { email, pageUri }
    },
    {
      manual: true
    }
  )
  useEffect(() => {
    if (data?.success === true && !loading) {
      setEmail('')
    }
  }, [data?.success, loading])

  useEffect(() => {
    setPageUri(window.location.href)
  }, [])
 <Container className={s['pre__footer']}>
            <Isotype className={s['isotype']} />
            <Heading
              as="h2"
              variant="md"
              centered
              style={{ textTransform: 'capitalize' }}
            >
              Sign-up for our <br /> Newsletter
            </Heading>

            <input
              type={'email'}
              placeholder={'Enter your email to stay updated'}
              value={email}
              onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
            />
            <button
              type={'submit'}
              onClick={() => refetch()}
              disabled={loading}
            >
              <ArrowLink />
              <span className="sr-only">Send</span>
            </button>
 </Container>
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the first error, if you're not using `response` then don't include it, it's as simple as that. You'd only need it if you want to use whatever is being returned from the `POST` request to the API, and it seems that's not the case.

The second error: You're getting a 404 error because you're calling your endpoint incorrectly. It should be:

```
const [{ loading }, refetch] = useAxios(
    {
      url: '/api/emailSignup', // removed "/pages" from this line
      method: 'POST',
      data: { email, pageUri }
    },
    {
      manual: true
    }
  )
```

This is because any file inside the folder `pages/api` is mapped to `/api/*` and will be recognized as an API endpoint instead of a page. This means that if your page is https://example.com you can access your `emailSignup` API endpoint on https://example.com/api/emailSignup.

**EDIT**: While reading [Hubspot's docs](https://legacydocs.hubspot.com/docs/methods/forms/submit_form_v3_authentication#:%7E:text=As%20this%20API%20is%20authenticated%2C), I noticed what could be a slight mistake in the url you're making a request to, please try this modification on your API endpoint and let me know if it works:

```
export default async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse<Response>) => {
  const { email, pageUri } = req.body
  const { method } = req

  if (method !== 'POST') {
    return res.status(405).end()
  }

  if (typeof email !== 'string') {
    return res.status(400).json({ success: false })
  }

  try {
    await axios({
      method: 'POST',
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-useless-escape
      url: `https://api.hsforms.com/submissions/v3/integration/secure/submit/${HUBSPOT_PORTAL_ID}/${HUBSPOT_FORM_GUID}?hapikey=${HUBSPOT_API_KEY}`,
      data: {
        fields: [{ name: 'email', value: email }],
        context: { pageUri },
      },
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    });
    res.status(200).json({ success: true, email })
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json({ success: false })
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip with response. Definitely makes sense and worked! With the 404 error, it's still happening even when I removed '/pages' from the endpoint.

Comment: Is the 404 happening on your API endpoint (you see the error on the terminal) or on the client-side (browser console)? Is your API file called  exactly `emailSignup`? Also, in your API endpoint, you should place the `response.status(200).json` at the end of the `try` block.

Comment: It's happening on the client side browser console. Yeah I've quadrupled checked the endpoint to make sure there's no typos. When I put the response.status(200).json at the end of the try block I now get a 500 error

Comment: I was reading the documentation of HubSpot and I think you got some errors in the API's url, I'll update my answer so you can try this modification.